# How to rotate text in Kofax Transformation?

Tags: text, rotation, kofax

I'am new in Kofax. Task - to recognize a couple of vertical words. Almost all text in document is horisontal. Only two words - vertical. In Kofax Capture I can do it easily:

My task - do the same in Kofax Transformation. I did not find a standard solution. I also could not find solution in Internet (for example some tricky script). Is this possible in Kofax Transformation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't add picture. Sorry. Text Rotation in Kofax Capture: Recognition Profiles -> Kofax High Rerfomance OCR Zonal -> Advanced -> Engine and other -> Text orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCR comes in two flavors in Kofax Transformations:

1. Page profiles. As the name suggests, a page profile is used to read the entirety of one individual page.
2. Zone profiles. These profiles are typically used with an Advanced Zone Locator.

Page profiles can rotate a given page. Imagine you have a document with three pages, and page number is is in landscape - if permitted, the OCR profile will rotate page number 2 while 1 and 3 will remain unchanged (i.e. portrait).

However, a page profile can only rotate the page as a whole -- not individual paragraphs or words. Moving forward, here are your options:

1. If your text appears always at the same location: use an Advanded Zone Locator.
2. If your text can be anywhere, try anchoring with a different locator (Format Locator), and move your AZL's zone by script (you can use some the parts from [this link](http://knowledgebase.kofax.com/faqsearch/results.aspx?QAID=17759)).
3. If neither is true or possible, you can rotate the page in script, and the re-execute a different page profile. [Here's some code](https://www.theorycrafter.org/quipu/swapping-ocr-representations-in-ktm/) to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wolfgang! Your answer is systematic and structured. I did not notice the option "Rotation" for AZL, sorry :( I think this will be enough for me. But I'm glad I asked a question. I found out what you can OCR in a script! Twice and as many times as you like! This is fundamental!

Comment: The only pity is that the code fragments from the link about the AZLr became inaccessible (SampleCode_CheckBoxDetection.txt, SampleCode_AddTheOMRZone.txt, SampleCode_AddTheOMRGroup.txt). Error: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." But the approach is clear. It's not a big problem.

Comment: When I was looking for a solution, I asked the same question in Russian. Just in case, I quote a link stating your answer in Russian: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064598/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-kofax-transformation

Comment: It was only recently that Kofax moved their KB behind a paywall (e.g. https://partner.kofax.com/s/login/ if you are a partner). Pretty sure the files are there if you happen to have access. Also, please be aware that re-OCRing your page(s) in script will reduce the page count by one.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about re-OCRing. A nice example of zone shift code can be found here: https://github.com/KofaxRPA/KTScripts/blob/master/TextLayoutRegistration.vb